How do I change output of variable in python?
My current code is
#imports
import requests
#setup
response = requests.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/")
fox = response.json()
#code
print(fox['image'])

Whenever I run it, it always prints something like https://randomfox.ca/images/99.jpg.
Is there any way to change this and make it 99.jpg instead?

Related: How can I get the base of a URL in Python?

import requests
import os

# Setup
response = requests.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/")
fox = response.json()

# Extract the filename
image_url = fox['image']
filename = os.path.basename(image_url)

# Code
print(filename)


Glad you found a working code sample! Please check out [answer] - the best answers contain code paired with an explanation of what you changed/what your sample is doing.
